# Execute a QUERY formula in google sheets using java

Tags: java, sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi I can connect and edit etc a google sheet using a java application however I would like to be able to query the google sheet using the QUERY language (ideally) to find and return a row with a particular cell in it. Reason being is that in large spreadsheets downloading and manually searching through all the data for one row with a particular cell in it is infeasible.
An example of what I'm looking for:

```
Sheets service = this.service;
ValueRange result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, "=QUERY(A:I,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I WHERE A = 'Random String'",1")).execute();
```

This is obviously incorrect as the range can't contain a formula however I was wondering if anyone is aware of a particular work around for this problem? A thought I had was potentially writing the formula to a cell and then reading the response, however this is very inefficient and ideally there is a java method of some sort that allows a formula query to the sheet with the response being the result?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something similar was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719239/how-can-i-use-the-google-sheets-v4-api-getbydatafilter-to-return-a-specific-ro however this answer is convoluted and requires use of curl, does anyone know a way to potentially translate this to java?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349362/how-to-perform-lookup-type-function-in-google-javascript is a solution however there is a question still on how memory intensive streaming the entire sheet would be, particularly in the case of large sheets. (It's not a real solution as it's still client side and not technically executed by the sheets api like a QUERY would be)